# How to update a pull request on bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

How do you update one of your own pull requests on bitbucket in your IDE on your local computer?

This workflow does not work as i expected:

1. Clone your fork
2. Checkout the branch you used for the pull request
3. Make changes
4. git add .
5. git commit
6. Push commit (to your fork repository)

So far so good but it seems that the pull request is not updated automatically as soon as the branch (on which the pull request is based) is updated.

Question: is there a way to let pull requests be updated (autoatically/manually) as soon as the branch (on which the pull requests is based) is updated?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Seems to me you asked a bit early.

http://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/04/22/bitbucket-now-auto-updates-pull-requests/

After updating my local branch and push, Bitbucket updated the pull-request automatically.

Comment: Atm the PR overview is not updated when adding further commits, but merging the PR will show also the new commits are respected.

Comment: What @1stthomas is saying is not the case with BitBucket Server 7.17. I have just tried adding a commit to an existing PR and it did not get merged.

Comment: @RonRonDK my observation was on a repository of the www site of bitbucket. And there it worked for me as I described.