# My pull request on GIT contains several commits done by others. How to prevent this behavior?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I created a branch (branch B) from branch A and did my changes and pushed it to branch B. Then I tried to make a pull request to branch A. But, my pull request contains several previous commits done by others (other team members). Why is this happening? How can I raise a clean PR which contains only my commits?

Edit:
The hosting site I am using is Bitbucket.

Comment: Note that *pull requests* are a feature of hosting sites, like GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, and so on. Each of these sites has its own special features around PRs. The answer to your question *is* a basic Git item, but you should also specify the hosting site, in case there are site-specific details.

Comment: @torek I am using BitBucket. I updated the question. But I don't think it is related to the hosting site. I think it could happen on any hosting site. In other terms, I think it is related to GIT.

Comment: Show the graph of your branch and the target branch. I bet there is a merge on your branch that should not be there. Or you did a rebase and you moved commits that you didn't create.

Comment: @axiac I can't share the graph because the repository is not owned by me. And, I don't have permission to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034766/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+request+commits

Comment: @phd The tagged question is not related to my question and it does not provide an answer. It's obvious that I can create a new branch and cherry-pick and apply those commits in my new branch. But, it is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: @SoulGood: Two points: (1) yes, I did say it's a basic Git item, it's just that the way to update a PR is hosting-site-specific. (2) Actually, the linked answer *is* the right answer. It's not framed in Bitbucket-specific terms, though.

Comment: @torek Agree with point 1 but strongly disagree with point 2. If point 2 is valid, then every time I came across this type of situation. I have to create a new branch, cherry-pick commits from my old branch, and raise a pr. Then I have to keep my old branch or delete it. Actually, it's obvious that it is not the most efficient answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preliminary note: I don't actually use Bitbucket and some of my terminology may be slightly off.  Specifically, I may be using some terms found only on Bitbucket here.  But Bitbucket and GitHub handle forks and pull requests (PRs) very similarly, fortunately, and it seems that about 6 or 7 years ago Bitbucket updated their PR machinery to match GitHub's (see [How to update a pull request on bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22357536/1256452)).

I'm also not sure if you're using a Bitbucket fork, or just working directly in a shared repository with separate branches.  I'm going to assume a fork but this should probably work the same in a shared repository (it does on GitHub).

> I created a branch (branch B) from branch A and did my changes and pushed it to branch B. Then I tried to make a pull request to branch A. But, my pull request contains several previous commits done by others (other team members). Why is this happening?

At the *Git* level, what we're really concerned with here are commits.  These are the entities that Git deals with, one whole commit at a time.  There are three or four things to know about here with each commit, depending on how you count these items:

1. Every commit has a unique hash ID.  This is the big ugly (40 characters, for SHA-1) [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number you see in `git log` output.  This hash ID is, in effect, the "true name" of the commit.  Any branch or tag or other names we use are just ways to let some Git repository *find* the correct hash ID.  Each Git repository—each fork or clone—has *its own private names*.  The fork mechanism on the hosting site provides a way to connect one hosted repository to another and view some or all names out of the other hosted repository, but it's always the *hash IDs* that really matter.
2. Commits are made up of snapshots and metadata.  Technically, the snapshot *is* metadata in the commit itself, but let's consider the snapshot first.  Each snapshot holds a full copy of every file that goes with that particular commit.  There are no *changes* here, just full snapshots.  This isn't too important for any given PR, but is important when we go to make copies of commits.
3. The *metadata* in any given commit give things like the author and committer (name, email, and date-and-time tuples) and the log message.  That is, the metadata contains the description of the commit.  The metadata in any one commit also has a list of *parent commit* hash IDs.  Most commits—the ones Git calls *ordinary* commits, if it bothers to given them any adjective at all—have exactly one parent hash ID.  This is the (single) earlier commit that comes *just before* the commit we're looking at now.
4. All parts of any commit are fully read-only.  This is how the hash IDs can work: the hash ID is simply a cryptographic checksum of the full contents of the commit.  The date-and-time-stamp usually makes a commit unique all by itself, but even if you manage to make multiple commits within a single second, or fake the timestamps, the parent commit hash ID(s) stored in the metadata of *this* commit differ from the parent commit hash ID(s) stored in the *parent* commit, and that alone serves to give this commit a unique hash ID.

(Item 4 could be part of item 1 depending on how you want to treat it.  Note that Git *finds* the commit by its hash ID, then *verifies that the hash ID matches the checksum of the stored data* as it extracts the commit object from the database.  This detects even a single bit of change as a corrupted commit, so that no part of any commit can ever change.)

The parent hash IDs wind up stringing commits together as backwards-looking chains.  We can draw this fairly simply, assuming ordinary commits, by using uppercase letters to stand in for the actual hash IDs.  If we put the latest commit, `H`, on the right, we get a drawing that looks like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Commit `H` contains, as its snapshot, all the files.  It contains in its (single) parent hash ID in its metadata the actual hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Git can thus use `H`'s metadata to find commit `G`.  This has a full snapshot as well, and by comparing the `G` and `H` snapshots, Git will find what we changed in commit `H`.  By using the metadata in `G`, Git can work its way back one more step, to commit `F`.

Commit `F` has a snapshot too, of course, and has its own metadata with yet another parent hash ID.  By following each commit backwards, one hop at a time, Git can work its way back to the very first commit anyone ever made for this repository.  That commit is special in that it has *no* parent hash IDs in it, which makes it what Git calls a *root commit*.  Git can now stop going backwards, having visited every commit leading to commit `H`.  This *is* the history in the repository, at least for the branch whose last commit is commit `H`.

Git *needs* the hash ID of commit `H` to do all of this.  To *get* that hash ID, Git can use your branch name.  For instance, if `H` is the last commit of branch `master`, we might draw it like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

The name `master` *points to* (locates) commit `H` in the database; commit `H` points back to `G`; and so on.  I stop drawing arrows at this point because of the way I draw branches:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

Here, the name `develop` points to `J`; `J` points to `I`; and `I` points to `H`.  Commits up through and including `J` are on develop, and commits up through and including `H` are on `master`.  This means many commits are on *both* branches.  That's a weird thing about Git, if you're used to other version control systems: commits appear and disappear from branches depending on where you put the *branch name*.

**It's not the branch names that matter!**  It's the *commits*.  The branch names are not *completely* irrelevant, since we use them to *find* the commits, but they're *mostly* irrelevant because we can change them around all we like.  For instance, GitHub now use `main` instead of `master`, and if you are a fan of this, you simply rename your `master` to `main` and now all the `master` commits are `main` commits instead.  In this particular example, we can even just *remove `master` entirely*, leaving only `develop`.  That's good enough because commit `I` leads backwards to commit `H`.

#### This isn't the way *humans* usually think of branches

When we look at a diagram like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K   <-- branch2
           \
            L   <-- branch3
```

a lot of *humans* will say that commits through `H` are on `master`, `I-J` are the commits that are on `branch1`, `K` is the only commit on `branch2`, and `L` is the only commit on `branch3`.

This is *not* how *Git* treats them.  Commits through `H` are on *all four* branches, and commit `K` is on two branches.  The three remaining commits are all just one one branch each.  To get Git and humans to agree on these things, what we end up doing is using *exclusion rules* of the form:

```
master..branch1
```

which really means: *the set of all commits reachable from `J`, minus the set of all commits reachable from `H`*.  This gives us the `I-J` pair.  Likewise `master..branch2` gives us just commit `K`, and `branch2..branch3` gives us just commit `L`.

#### Branch names are not the only kinds of names

Besides *branch* names, Git can find commits by lots of other kinds of names.  On GitHub, for instance, *pull requests* cause names of the form `refs/pull/number/head` to appear in the repository to which the PR is made.  This particular name is linked, on GitHub, to some branch name in some repository—your branch name in your fork, for instance, or your branch name in the same repository via sharing.

(Bitbucket uses slightly different names, but the concepts match up.)

#### Your situation

We can't see the various names in the various repositories, but we can approximate them.  You yourself can only see *some* of these names sometimes, depending on many things (including whether you made a fork, and the rules of the hosting site).  But we know, from your complaint that someone else's commits are contained in your PR, that the actual situation in the repository in which the PR is asking some human to add commits, looks a bit like this one:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- someone-elses-work
              \
               K   <-- your-PR
```

The one commit you made, commit `K`, comes *after* the two commits that someone else made: `I-J`.  Your pull request asks that they—whoever "they" are—incorporate your commit `K`, into *their branch* `master`.  GitHub call this the *base branch* of the pull request.

Because commits can't be changed, it's only possible for them to add commit `K` by adding *all three* commits.  So your PR asks for all these commits to be added.

> How can I raise a clean PR which contains only my commits?

You must make new commits.

> [According to the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034718/1256452], I have to create a new branch, cherry-pick commits from my old branch, and raise a [new] pr

These particular *steps* are not necessary, and in particular the "raise a new PR" is no longer required at Bitbucket (but was back in 2014).  The overall *idea*, however, is generally right.

Assuming the diagram I drew is accurate (or close enough), commit `K` *is* the problem.  It adds on to commit `J`.  You want instead a commit that adds on to commit `H`.  To achieve this, you *must* make a new and improved commit—a cherry-pick, in other words.

Let's re-draw the branch diagram in *your* repository, though, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- branch-X
              \
               K   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

(the extra `HEAD`, in parentheses, indicates that your current branch name is `feature`, so that `K` is your current commit).

You *could* create a new branch name pointing to commit `H`, and get onto that branch:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature2 (HEAD), master
         \
          I--J   <-- branch-X
              \
               K   <-- feature
```

and then cherry-pick `K` to a copy, which we can call `K'`:

```
          K'  <-- feature2 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- branch-X
              \
               K   <-- feature
```

Then you could delete `feature` entirely, rename `feature2` to `feature`, and use `git push -f` to update your Bitbucket fork, or the shared Bitbucket repository, which would cause Bitbucket to automatically update your PR.

Or, you can simply run:

```
git rebase --onto master branch-X
```

(without ever creating `feature2`).  Your Git will then:

- use *detached HEAD* mode, like this, to get to commit `H`:

  ```
  ...--G--H   <-- HEAD, master
           \
            I--J   <-- branch-X
                \
                 K   <-- feature
  ```
- having listed out commit `K`'s hash ID (using `branch-X..feature` internally<sup>1</sup>), cherry-pick commit `K` to get `K'`; and finally
- force the name `feature` to point to `K'`.

The final result is:

```
          K'  <-- feature
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- branch-X
              \
               K   [abandoned]
```

but without as much motion on your part—no separate `git checkout` and `git cherry-pick` operations, for instance—and without the minor pain of having to delete the old `feature` and then rename the temporary branch name, and the associated headaches of losing any associated upstream, and so on.  So this is definitely a more *user-efficient* way to get where you want to go.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, the internals for `git rebase` are much more complicated than this.  There's the fork-point magic, the `--no-merges` part, and the symmetric difference and cherry-mark / `git cherry` upstream-equivalent elision.  But the `stop..start` stuff is where to start, and for this case, none of the complications should get in the way.  Still, that's why tutorials should start with cherry-pick instead of rebase!

---

#### The "base branch" is important

I don't know what Bitbucket call it, but when raising a PR, the "base branch" is how GitHub determine the range of commits you're actually asking to merge (by specifying the merge target branch name).  GitHub's mechanism for this is overly complicated and they refuse to show the actual commit *graph*, which makes this quite tricky.  You are allowed to change the base branch of a PR; the effects of this are also tricky: it's not clear to me, for instance, what happens if you move to a descendant commit, then back to the original commit, or even one of its ancestors.